# How to join two tables from different databases(MySql, Vertica) in Java code?

Tags: java, mysql, vertica

I have a Java batch job that needs to do an outer join between data from MySql and Vertica. I'm thinking I have to dump data from the two tables into a Map and compare the keys. Does anyone know of a better technique or library that makes this easy to do?

Comment: AFAIK, you'll have to do manual processing here. NB: manual include copying one db system data into the other and process with an usual join

Comment: you wanted to use table from both the db at the same time rite ?

Comment: @A5l-lE5 yes, although it doesn't have to be instant, since it's a batch job, and the data from either table will very likely be consistent for good amount of time.

Comment: it can be possible if you do create connections from both ,get data data from both.until and unless it is done one after another.

Comment: @RC. Thanks but due to some time constraints and database write access reasons(reading from slave), I think that's not an option at the moment!

Comment: Load data from one database into the other and then join. If this isn't an option, you'll have to do it at the application level.

Comment: Why not using an linked external table ?

Comment: @Kermit Unfortunately the MySQL table is a result of a running job, and the job that could create and update Vertica has already been run, or part of a different workflow....

Comment: @Up_One Thanks, I hadn't thought of that, but because I don't have access to the code that updates Vertica, I'm not sure I can do it in time!

Comment: This would be the best way i think couse of Vertica ease of working with external tables

Answer (score 2):

Why not using an external table : 
**Create the table in MySQL**

```
 CREATE TABLE federated_table (
        id     INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        other  INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        PRIMARY KEY  (id),
        INDEX name (name),
        INDEX other_key (other)
    )
    ENGINE=FEDERATED
    DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
    CONNECTION='mysql://fed_user@remote_host:9306/federated/test_table';
```

**And you can use it in Vertica to join data from it :**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ext1 (x integer) AS COPY FROM '/tmp/ext1.dat' DELIMITER ',';
```

You can join regural and external tables in Vertica from version 7 up

---

Another solution is using Pentaho or Talend to do this for you is a free ETL tool very good and easy to use !

Comment: Ah thanks, but unfortunately our version is 6.1.X, but still I'll look into this.

Comment: what about pentaho ! it has connectors to both ! and can query and merge the result as you want !